# SQL Server 2008 : update increment logic difficulty

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, Visual studio 2012 C#.NET4.5, win-forms

I have a data grid that contains lets say 20 records, theirs a field call "NewPareto" this field contains 1-20 as integers, basically a league score.  Please note this field must allow for nulls.

If a user in the grid changes position 9 to position 3, I need a query that will resort the records AFTER the position that was updated, basically I was thinking simply increment by 1.

However I've found this doesn't work as there's always a gap where 9 used to be and if i say anything greater than 3, there already is a 3 that exists.

I was thinking about changing the original 3 to 4 then saying increment > 4. but this still doesn't sort out the 9, on top of this, it would seem the logic doesn't work when swapping a low number to a high.

I've tried some query that latest one doesn't work either.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IncrimentPareto]
    @pg varchar(255),
    @Pareto int,
    @paretostatic int
AS
   ;With cte as
   (select top 1000000 * 
    from ParetoMain 
    where PG = @pg and 
          NewPareto > @paretostatic and 
          NewPareto is not null
    order by Sales desc )
   UPDATE cte 
   SET @Pareto = NewPareto = @Pareto +1
```

this almost works but there are two 3s that still exist now, and it only works after the position 8, since 9 doesn't exist.

Hopefully your heads aren't frazzled like mine is.

Summary: query that sorts records with new league numbers after a certain position has been moved up OR down the league

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a single update statement which will only update the rows for which the pareto changes using the row_number function, and a bit of judicious sub-querying:

```sql
DECLARE @from int = 9, @to int = 3

UPDATE MainPareto 
SET pareto = m.new_pareto
FROM (
    SELECT pKey, -- this is your primary key for the table
    new_pareto = row_number() 
    over(ORDER BY   CASE WHEN pareto = @from THEN @to ELSE pareto END, 
                    CASE WHEN pareto = @from THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
    FROM MainPareto
    -- put in any conditions that you want to restrict the scores by.
    WHERE PG = @pg AND pareto IS NOT NULL
    -- end condtions
) as m
INNER JOIN MainPareto ON MainPareto.pKey = m.pKey
WHERE MainPareto.pareto <> m.new_pareto
```

The order by clause of the "row_number() over" orders by new pareto, giving precedence to the new entry. If you want the older one to maintain it's lead, swap the 0 and 1 of the second order by clause.

Comment: excellent, ill go check this later currently stuck on a job i need to complete, so bare with me and ill get back to you cheers Jonathan

Comment: mate that is superb! works perfect! havent fully tested but i take it it also works if the from is 3 and the to is 9?

Comment: @StevenSmith Yes. It'll even work of you try to move it to a number which doesn't exist. It'll stop at 1 (if you try to move to 0 or less) or the maximum number of items if you try to move to a number bigger than that (in your original case: 20).

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use option with CTE and ROW_NUMBER() ranking function

```
DECLARE @Pareto int = 2,
        @NewPareto int = 5
;WITH cte AS
 ( 
  SELECT ID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE WHEN Pareto = @Pareto THEN @NewPareto ELSE Pareto END) AS Pareto, Col1
  FROM dbo.test87
  WHERE Pareto != @Pareto
  ),cte2 AS
 (
  SELECT ID, Pareto, @NewPareto AS NewPareto, Col1
  FROM dbo.test87
  WHERE Pareto = @Pareto  
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, Pareto, CASE WHEN Pareto >= @NewPareto THEN Pareto + 1 ELSE Pareto END, Col1
  FROM cte
  )
  UPDATE t
  SET t.Pareto = c.NewPareto
  FROM dbo.test87 t JOIN cte2 c ON t.ID = c.ID
```

Demo on [**SQLFIddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb937/1)